# How to update documents accross multiple cores in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I have 2 solr cores. The data in the second core is basically some subset of data in the first core, grouped differently.

At the moment, when some data changes, I send 2 updates (1 to each core).

Is it possible to update both cores with a single update? Basically, I want to update first core, and second core should be updated automatically, based on some predefined rules.